# Reuse a filestream in C++?

Tags: c++, filestream, argv

I have a program that takes multiple files as input. What I'm trying to do is use the same filestream? I keep getting an error when trying to open the stream with the second file. Why is not code not valid and creating an error at compile time? argv[2] is a const char*.

error: no match for call to '(std::ifstream) (char*&)'

```
ifstream fin(argv[1]);
  //work with filestream
fin.close();

fin(argv[2]);
  //work with filestream
fin.close();
```

Comment: Wow, maybe calling the constructor was a bad habit to get in to as a short hand. Thanks that solved my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line `ifstream fin(argv[1]);` is evoking `ifstream`'s constructor, and the constructor can only be called once per object.  Your code is trying to call it a second time.  Try using [open()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/open/) instead:

```
fin.open(argv[2]);
```

As an aside, you may also want to call [clear()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/clear/) before you reopen your `ifstream`.  The reason for this is that if the first open() (or even close()) fails, error bits on the `ifstream` will be set, and won't be cleared by close().

Comment: Wow, maybe calling the constructor was a bad habit to get in to as a short hand. Thanks that solved my problem.

Comment: @LF4 I would say the opposite, its an excellent habit. RAII is one of the most powerful constructs of C++

Comment: @AndreasBrinck You beat me to it ;)

Comment: @LF4: If he solved your problem, the correct thing to do is accept his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a local scope:

```
{
  ifstream fin(argv[1]);
  //work with filestream
}

{

  ifstream fin(argv[2]);
  //work with filestream
}
```

Note that you dont manually need to close the streams, this is handled automatically when they go out of scope.

Comment: This is a good solution too, though local scope might look weird to the uninitiated.  Not having to worry about error flags is a plus.

Comment: As I said in my other comment, it's a good general habit to get into. I always try to limit the scope of my variables as much as possible.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck A great way to limit scope is to create a function.